# package of python dfply in ubuntun

Tags: python, pandas

hello friends I am trying to install the dfply package in python from ubuntu I have googled and it does not appear to me the way try with

```
pip install dfply
```

it is observed that it installs something but when calling it does not recognize it my python is 3 and already installed pandas I could get its orientation